# Django app for auto delete file

Tags: django-apps

I have a problem on deleting my files in the media. If I delete my files for example in the admin, it works but the file remains on my media folder. I wanted to delete it too.
Is there an app that automatically delete old file and deletes files on models deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try django-cleanup but beware on the consequences. Read their information. I advice to create a signal instead using an app.